# How to sum using a Join

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to sum while using a Join

I am trying to run the query below. When I run it, it shows no results. I am trying to list out each AppUsers name and their hours for the current month.

```
Select a.UserNm, sum(isnull(b.hrs, 0))Hours
from Appuser a
    JOIN EquipWorkOrderHrs b 
        on a.UserID = b.UserID
Where a.DelFlg = 0 and DateTm between DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getDate()), 0) and DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, -1, getDate()), -1)
Group by a.UserNm
Order by a.UserNm
```

If I run just a query on the hours I get 715.25

```
SELECT sum (Hrs) FROM EquipWorkOrderHrs
```

After Looking in to this more I should of added a third table, I was looking a the wrong tables DateTm. What I have below show the three tables I need to make this work. When I run this I get a error saying the multi-part identifier "c.EquipWorkOrderID" could not be bound.

```
Select a.UserNm, sum(isnull(c.hrs, 0))Hours
from Appuser a
    JOIN EquipWorkOrder b 
        on b.EquipWorkOrderID = c.EquipWorkOrderID
    JOIN EquipWorkOrderHrs c 
            on a.UserID = c.UserID
Where a.DelFlg = 0 and b.DateTm between DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getDate()), 0) and DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, -1, getDate()), -1)
Group by a.UserNm
Order by a.UserNm
```

Comment: your `DateTm between`conditions seem to be in the wrong order. It should be `between DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, -1, getDate()), -1) and DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getDate()), 0)`

Comment: I tried it as you suggested, still the same results

Comment: What is the date condition suppose to be? This month? Last month?

Comment: Date condition is for this month

Comment: Could you provide example data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would debug the queries in steps, to see where the query breaks.

The first step was already performed by you:

**Step 1**

```
SELECT sum (Hrs) FROM EquipWorkOrderHrs
```

**Step 2 - Join**

```
SELECT sum (b.Hrs)
from Appuser a
    JOIN EquipWorkOrderHrs b 
        on a.UserID = b.UserID
```

**Step 3 - WHERE condition #1**

```
SELECT sum (b.Hrs)
from Appuser a
    JOIN EquipWorkOrderHrs b 
        on a.UserID = b.UserID
Where a.DelFlg = 0
```

**Step 4 - WHERE condition #2**

```
SELECT sum (b.Hrs)
from Appuser a
    JOIN EquipWorkOrderHrs b 
        on a.UserID = b.UserID
Where a.DelFlg = 0 
and DateTm between DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getDate()), 0) and DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, -1, getDate()), -1)
```

**Edit for new question**
You are joining the tables in wrong order - you are referencing `c.EquipWorkOrderID` in thejoin condition of table `EquipWorkdOrder b` before you join table `EquipWorkOrderHrs c` . Try the following:

```
Select a.UserNm, sum(isnull(c.hrs, 0))Hours
from Appuser a
    JOIN EquipWorkOrderHrs c 
            on a.UserID = c.UserID
    JOIN EquipWorkOrder b 
        on b.EquipWorkOrderID = c.EquipWorkOrderID
Where a.DelFlg = 0 and b.DateTm between DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getDate()), 0) and DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, -1, getDate()), -1)
Group by a.UserNm
Order by a.UserNm
```

Comment: step 1, 2 and 3 return the number, step 4 returns null. I am trying to list each person and there total hours for the current month, not a overall sum of all the hours. Maybe I am going about this the wrong way.

Comment: I updated my original post, I was looking at the wrong table for the DateTm

Comment: See Edit in answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the current month, you can use:

```
Select a.UserNm, sum(coalesce(ewoh.hrs, 0))Hours
from Appuser a join
     EquipWorkOrderHrs ewoh
     on a.UserID = ewoh.UserID
Where a.DelFlg = 0 and
      DateTm >= datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1)
Group by a.UserNm
Order by a.UserNm;
```

This assumes there is no future dated data.  If there is, use:

```
Where a.DelFlg = 0 and
      DateTm >= datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1) and
      DateTm < dateadd(month, 1, datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1))
```

Comment: I tried it as you suggested, still the same results

Comment: @JShaffer . . . Perhaps you have no data from the current month.